# How do I pass a React prop from Parent to Child, to another Child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, prop

I currently have my Parent set up as follows, which I'm then passing props to

```
 class WorkoutPlan extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      workoutPlan: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/api/workout-plan")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ workoutPlan: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { workoutPlan } = this.state;
    // const workoutPlan = this.state.workoutPlan;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{workoutPlan.Name}</h1>
        <button className="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click Me
        </button>
        <Workout {...workoutPlan.workout} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in my  child, I'm wanting to pass those same props to another Child

```
import React from "react";
import Exercise from "./Exercise";

const Workout = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>"Workout for {props.day}"</h2>
      <Exercise {...workoutPlan.workout} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Workout;
```

I can't seem to figure out how I would go about doing this. I'm being told that the setup is exactly the same as the 1st child, but when I enter in the same code, it's not working.

Comment: `<Exercise {...props.workoutPlan.workout} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `{...props}` to your `Exercise` component so your Workout component should look like this

```
import React from "react";
import Exercise from "./Exercise";

const Workout = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>"Workout for {props.day}"</h2>
      <Exercise {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Workout;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass props destructuring it, the effect it's the same as you were passing props one by one.

You can't achieve your goal because in your Workout component there is no "workout" prop.

Try to pass props to Exercise component like this:

```
<Exercise {...props} />
```